# How to TF-IDF transform an InstanceList of FeatureVectors - MALLET

Tags: machine-learning, text-classification, mallet

I have a MALLET InstanceList where the data fields of the Instance objects are MALLET FeatureVector's.

I want to TF-IDF transform them with the same effect as http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfTransformer.html

Is there an existing library or some part of the MALLET API that does this?

Comment: I also think this functionality would be useful, please post here if you made any progresso this. You probably would have to use something like Lucene for it, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/27233433/3229995